# What's the difference between sorted and sort in Array

Tags: swift

In **Swift 3**, what is the difference between:

```
self.myArray.sort(by: { $0.name > $1.name })
```

And

```
let newSortedArray = self.myArray.sorted(by: { $0.name > $1.name })
```

The effect seems to be the same, but I need to pass the result of the second one to another Array (or to itself?), to be able to use it.

What is the difference? Help is very appreciated.

In this example `myArray` is an Array of `struct Whatever {var name: String ""}`

Comment: Needless parentheses make kittens cry.

Comment: @Alexander `1)` edited and `2)`, since that comment of yours, I made sure not to use any needless ones anymore. so thank you for bettering my code ;)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`sort` mutates the array it is called on so its items are sorted. `sorted` returns a copy of the array it is called on with the values sorted.

If the original order of your array is important, calling `sort` on it would cause serious problems.

Also, if you have a giant array that contained value types and called `sorted` on it, it would duplicate each value and double the memory usage.

Comment: so basically the fact that i need to pass the result of `sorted` is the only difference?

Comment: Not exactly. If the original order of your array is important, calling `sort` on it would cause serious problems. Also, if you have a giant array that contained value types and called `sorted` on it, it would duplicate each value and double the memory usage.

Comment: I see. maybe you want to add this comment to your answer. seems important to me. in case someone else has a similar question

Answer (score 13):

Note that the convention in swift 3 is that if you have a present tense verb like sort or reverse it is a mutating function (the original collection is modified), whereas if you have a past participle or gerund, like enumerated, appending or sorted then you are getting a copy.  In cases where this is ambiguous because the operation is already a noun, like union the mutating version is named with form: formUnion.

Answer (score 2):

**Three types of sort functions are available in swift(5.4) :**

1.`sort()`

2.`sorted()`

3.`sorted(by:)`

Now See below examples  and understand the whole thing :-

**Create an example array on which you will execute all functions**

```
var sortEx =  [1,4,0,10]
```

1. `sort()` :When you don't want to store sorted array  result in another array (only changes should be reflect in to same array).

Still if you will try to store result in to another fresh array it will be always an empty array
changes will reflect in same array

```
  sortEx.sort()
  print(sortEx) //[0, 1, 4, 10]

  //force try to store result in another array by sort()
  let freshArray = sortEx.sort()
  print(freshArray) //()
  print(sortEx) //[0, 1, 4, 10]
```

2. `sorted()` : it will give a copy of fresh  sorted array and existing array will be in original state  always.

`var aSort = sortEx.sorted()`

`print(aSort)//[0, 1, 4, 10]`

`print(sortEx)//[1, 4, 0, 10]`

3. `sorted(by:)` : By this function you can sort ascending/descending both side by `>` and `<` keywords and your old original array will not disturb.

**Asc:**

`var sortedAscArray = sortEx.sorted(by: <)`

`print(sortedAscArray)//[0, 1, 4, 10]`

`print(sortEx)//[1, 4, 0, 10]`

**Dsc:**

`var sortedDscArray = sortEx.sorted(by: >)`

`print(sortedDscArray)//[10, 4, 1, 0]`

`print(sortEx)//[1, 4, 0, 10]`

Apple Reference for more learning :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort

Happy Coding! **:)**

Answer (score 1):

As per Swift 3.0, we have to functions sorted() and sorted(by:), where sorted() will return array of values from ascending order and in sorted(by:) you can make it ascending or descending.

```
let array = [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[6,7],[8,9]]

print(array.flatMap{$0}.sorted())

print(array.flatMap{$0}.sorted(by: {$0>$1}))

output : 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```